# Continuity of linear map on tensor product spaces with different norm properties

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ra.rings-and-algebras, banach-spaces, tensor-products

I originally asked this question on StackExchange, but I think that it may be more suitable to here.

Let $V$ and $U$ be Banach spaces. I'm considering a linear map $\phi: V \rightarrow U$, and extending this to a map $\phi^k: V^{\otimes k} \rightarrow U^{\otimes k}$ defined by

$$
\phi^k(v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_k) = \phi(v_1) \otimes \ldots \otimes \phi(v_k).
$$

I aim to extend this linearly to an arbitrary tensor which might be a sum of pure tensors, i.e.,

$$
v = \sum_{i=1}^n v_{1i} \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{ki}.
$$

Upon trying to prove the continuity of $\phi^k$, assuming a "subtensorial" inequality  of the norms on both tensor product spaces:

$$
\|v_1 \otimes \ldots \otimes v_k\| \leq \|v_1\| \cdot \ldots \cdot \|v_k\|,
$$

I arrived at the inequality:

$$
\|\phi^k(v)\| \leq M^k \sum_{i=1}^n  \|v_{1i}\| \cdot \ldots \cdot \|v_{ki}\|
$$

where $M$ is a bound on the operator norm of $\phi$.

I realized that the right-hand side doesn't represent the norm of $v$ directly. However, considering this inequality holds for any representation of $v$ as a sum of pure tensors, we can see that the right-hand side is bounded by the projective norm of $v$ in $V^{\otimes k}$, i.e.

$$\|v\|_{\text{projective}} := \text{inf}\,\Big\{\sum_{i=1}^n   \|v_{1i}\| \cdot \ldots \cdot \|v_{ki}\|   \\ \text{ : } v = \sum_{i=1}^n  v_{1i} \otimes \ldots \otimes v_{ki} \Big\}.$$

So, it appears $\phi^k$ would be continuous if $V^{\otimes k}$ is endowed with the projective norm, while $U^{\otimes k}$ retains the submultiplicative property.

It seems like I need the projective norm on $V^{\otimes k}$ in order to make $\phi^k$ continuous. That my subtensorial inequality isn’t enough for the norm on $V^{\otimes k}$. Is this correct? Would continuity hold perhaps instead if we endowed $V^{\otimes k}$ with the injective norm instead?

**PS**: In fact, I am trying to prove an extended version of a known property of the free tensor algebra. Traditionally, it is known that for any linear map $\phi:V \to U$, there exists a unique algebra homomorphism $\tilde{\phi}$ that extends it as a map $T(V) \to T(U)$, where for $a \in \bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty V^{\otimes k} = T(V)$, $\tilde{\phi}(a) = (\phi^k(a^k))_{k\geq 0} \in T(U)$.

The question I am trying to elucidate is whether it can be proven that a linear and continuous $\phi$ is extendable to a continuous algebra homomorphism. This seems to necessitate imposing the projective norm on the tensor powers of $V$, ensuring that the $\phi^k$'s are continuous homomorphisms. It seems that the subtensorial inequality is not a sufficient requirement for the norm on $V^{\otimes k}$.

Thank you.

Comment: You should consult, e.g., the book of Defant and Floret *Tensor norms and Operator Ideals* and look for the **metric mapping property** of tensor norms.

Comment: From what I’ve been seeing, it’s not clear at all what happens, if you impose the projective norm on the base space and a subtensorial norm on the target space, you get continuity of the $\phi^k$’s. But from discussions I’ve been having, by duality, it seems that you can perhaps impose the injective norm on the target space for similar outcomes